# Copy a large amount of files in s3 on the same bucket

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I got a "directory" on a s3 bucket with 80 TB ~ and I need do copy everything to another directory in the same bucket

**source** = s3://mybucket/abc/process/

**destiny** = s3://mybucket/cde/process/

I already tried to use aws s3 sync, but worked only for the big files, still left 50 TB to copy. I'm thinking about to use a boto3 code as this example below, but I don't know how to do for multiple files/directories recursively.

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
copy_source = {
    'Bucket': 'mybucket',
    'Key': 'mykey'
}
s3.meta.client.copy(copy_source, 'otherbucket', 'otherkey')
```

How can I do this using the boto3?

Comment: "I already tried to use aws s3 sync, but worked only for the big files" Why did it not work for the other files? Why not post that problem with the command you used, and the problem you encountered as a question here?

Comment: What I ran: ```aws s3 sync s3://mybucket/abc/process/ s3://mybucket/cde/process/```

after having copied a good amount (but very slowly), it started to return this error: 
```fatal error: An error occurred (RequestTimeTooSkewed) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: The difference between the request time and the current time is too large.```

Comment: Did you try running `aws s3 sync` a second time? It should be able to quickly skip all the files that had been copied already and continue with the ones that failed. Also, you might want to sync the time on the computer you are running the command with a NTP server.

Comment: Yes, same error

Comment: Something is wrong with your local machine's clock if you're seeing that error.  It's probably best to just spin up an EC2 instance in the correct region, and run the command remotely if it's a one time activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there may be better ways of doing this using bucket policies, it can be done using boto3.
first you will need to get a list of the contents of the bucket

```
bucket_items =   s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=source_bucket,Prefix=source_prefix)
bucket_contents = bucket_items.get('Contents',[])
```

Where source_bucket is the name of the bucket and source_prefix is the name of the folder. 
Next you will iterate over the contents and for each item call the s3.meta.client.copy method like so

```
for content in bucket_contents:
        copy_source = {
            'Bucket': source_bucket,
            'Key': content['Key']
        }
        s3.meta.client.copy(copy_source, source_bucket, destination_prefix + '/' + content['Key'].split('/')[-1])
```

the contents are a dictionary so you must use 'Key' to get the name of the item and use split to break it into prefix and file name.

Comment: I think there something wrong on the split on de Key
Example:
```print('destination_path' + '/' + content['Key'].split('/')[-1])```

output: ```destination_path/file.parquet```
how should be: ```destination_path/year=2018/month=06/day=15/file.parquet```

Comment: In your example destination_path is in quotes. it should be a variable with the name of the folder you are placing them into.

Comment: ```source_bucket = 'mybucket'
destination_prefix = 'cde/process/file.parquet'```

```print(copy_source, source_bucket, destination_prefix + '/' + content['Key'].split('/')[-1])```

Output: ```{'Bucket': 'mybucket', 'Key': 'abc/process/year=2018/month=01/day=14/file.parquet'} mybucket cde/process/file.parquet```

Comment: I need to keep the same directory structure. 
destination_prefix + '/' + content['Key'].split('/')[-1] should return ```cde/process/year=2018/month=01/day=14/file.parquet``` but its returning ```cde/process/file.parquet```

Comment: Ah, I understand now. content['Key'].split('/')[-1] returns only the name you will have to use '/'.join(content['Key'].split('/')[n:]) where n is the start point of where the similarity of the folder structure is needed. so if the source prefix is  abc/process/year=2018/month=01/day=14/file.parquet then you would use '/'.join(content['Key'].split('/')[2:])

Comment: Now I'm getting SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing.
Code: ```s3r.meta.client.copy(copy_source, source_bucket, destination_prefix + '/'.join(content['Key'].split('/')[2:]) ```

Comment: It looks like you missed a ) at the end.